# How to solve $dx/dt=x^3-x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the differential equation:
$$
\frac{dx}{dt}=x^3-x.
$$
If we seek a solution $x$ such that there exist $t_0\in\mathbb R$ verifying $x(t_0)$ equal to $0$, $1$ or $-1$, we find using the unicity in the Cauchy-Lischitz theorem that the solution $x$ is given by:
\begin{align*}
x(t)=0 \;\forall t\in \mathbb R\mbox{ if }x(t_0)=0\\
x(t)=1 \;\forall t\in \mathbb R\mbox{ if }x(t_0)=1\\
x(t)=-1 \;\forall t\in \mathbb R\mbox{ if }x(t_0)=-1
\end{align*}
Then, I want to know how to deal with the other situation where $x$ does not take the values $0$, $1$ and $-1$?

Comment: Swich variables first

Comment: Write $dt/dx=1/(x^3-x)$. Use partial fractions and integrate.

Comment: You can take a look at Wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables

Comment: You can also divide the equation by $x^3$ and then let $y=1/x^2$.

Comment: Apart from the direct Bernoulli trick, you can also modify it to include more structure of the right side and set $y=1-x^{-2}$.

Comment: Please don't use inappropriate tags. I have removed the PDE, differential-forms, and cauchy-problem tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rearrange:

$$\frac{1}{x^3 - x}dx = dt$$

Left-hand side is now factorable for partial fraction decomposition:

$$\frac{1}{x(x - 1)(x+1)}\,dx = dt$$

$$\frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{x - 1} + \frac{C}{x+1} = \frac{1}{x^3 -x} \\
Ax^2 - A + Bx^2 + Bx + Cx^2 - Cx = 1$$

We can then get three equations from this:
$$ A + B + C = 0 \\
B - C = 0 \\
-A = 1
$$
Therefore
$$ A = -1, B = \frac{1}{2}, C = \frac{1}{2}$$

Now our equation is:

$$-\frac{1}{x}\,dx + \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{x - 1}\,dx + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{x + 1}\,dx = dt $$

Integrating yields:

$$ -\ln(x) + \frac{1}{2}\ln(x - 1) + \frac{1}{2}\ln(x + 1) = t + C $$

We can get rid of the fractions and solve for $x$:

$$-2\ln(x) + \ln(x - 1) + \ln(x + 1) = 2t + C \\
\ln\left(\frac{x^2 - 1}{x^2}\right) = 2t + C \\
\frac{x^2 - 1}{x^2} = e^{2t + C} = Ce^{2t} \\
x^2 - 1 = Ce^{2t}\,x^2 \\
-1 = Ce^{2t}\,x^2 - x^2 \\
-1 = x^2(Ce^{2t} - 1) \\
\frac{-1}{Ce^{2t} - 1} = x^2 \\
x = \pm\sqrt{\frac{-1}{Ce^{2t} - 1}}
$$

Comment: Your solution works if for the initial condition we have $x(t_0) > 1$. There is also another general solution that's the opposite sign of yours, which is easy to see from the starting ODE since the RHS is given by an odd function in $x$.

Comment: What you did is not "integration by parts" but "partial fraction decomposition".

Comment: @Ennar the solution works also for $0<x(t_0)<1$ by rendering $C<0$. Note the different behavior in this case versus having $x(t_0)>1$ when $t$ is allowed to increase without bound.

Comment: @Oscar Lanzi, I'm refering to the step where it's written $-\ln(x) + \frac{1}{2}\ln(x - 1) + \frac{1}{2}\ln(x + 1) = t + C$, since the domain of the LHS is $x > 1$. Of course, this can be avoided by immediately writing $\ln\left| \frac{x^2-1}{x^2}\right|$. There is also something to be said about uniqueness because it's a separable ODE and we need to be careful of the sign of $x^3-x$, but all of this is probably taken care just by writing $1-1/x^2 = Ce^{2t}$ and considering $C$ of any sign, as you said. But I'm not an expert, so I'll leave it at "probably" :)

Comment: Thanks @emacsdrivesmenuts - I shouldn’t be explaining problems before coffee.

Comment: @Ennar - this is probably controversial, but I usually just consider it to be the complex log function since you are allowed different choices of constants at a discontinuity.

Comment: @johnnyb that's fine if you let $C$ be locally constant and take complex values. But I'm not sure if in the end it's clear that we can take $C$ to be locally constant real function, while if we just look at the real part of complex logarithm, which is simply $\ln|z|$, everything is much more straightforward. I guess it doesn't matter too much, except that in the final step you should include the negative solution as well.

Answer (score 3):

The equation is of Bernoulli type, so a first sensible operation is dividing by $x^3$,
$$x^{-3}\dot x=1-x^{-2}.$$

Thus define $y=1-x^{-2}$, then
$$
\dot y=2x^{-3}\dot x=2y\implies y(t)=y_0e^{2(t-t_0)},~~~1-x(t)^{-2}=(1-x_0^{-2})e^{2(t-t_0)}
$$
or
$$
x(t)=\frac{x_0}{\sqrt{(1-x_0^2)e^{2(t-t_0)}+x_0^2}}
$$
for as long as the term under the root is positive. This is always the case for $t=t_0$.

Comment: Aren't you missing another solution with opposite sign? To obtain the last expression you need to compute a square root.

Comment: I understand: the initial value $x(0)=x_0$ makes you keeps only the positive one.

Comment: Yes, you have to ensure that the initial point matches and then that there are no discontinuities on the solution function. Or rather, end the solution at the singularities, if present.